# Please help me figure out the meaning of "corporate landscape"

Tags: phrase-meaning

May it mean the whole picture of an organization?

I came across this phrase in an article headline of *The Economist* called "The creep of consolidation across the America's corporate landscape."

Comment: Where did you see it used? Can you post a quote? What do reference works say about the phrase?

Comment: It's a rather "pliable" term, but comes closer to meaning the social structure, economics, and politics in which the corporation (or group of related corporations) operates.

Comment: I came across this phrase in an article headline of The economist called "The creep of consolidation across the America's corporate landscape".

Comment: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landscape) gives the metaphorical extension: 'landscape: a particular area of activity'; the terms 'scene' ('on the sporting scene' etc) and 'world' ('business world' etc) are more commonly used.

Comment: It does not mean "the whole picture of an organization". It means "the whole picture of *all* organizations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means the current external conditions within which a corporation is operating, whether they are economic, political, societal, etc.

For example, "The current corporate landscape is helping us to acquire new technology by way of buyouts."

Comment: Right—the crucial point with "corporate landscape"—and one that I'm not sure the poster would be able to glean from further independent research—is that the term describes the economic environment that one or more corporations find themselves in, not the economic environment within a particular corporation. In other words, as you indicate, it is externally directed rather than internally directed.